# .htaccess redirect directory and subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with the following redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /mainfolder http://www.test.com/newlink1
Redirect 301 /mainfolder/subfolder http://www.test.com/newlink2
```

1st redirect works fine, but 2nd one inestead of redirecting to /newlink2 goes to

```
http://www.test.com/newlink1/subfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

I put longer redirect first in .htaccess and it fixed the problem:

```
Redirect 301 /mainfolder/subfolder http://www.test.com/newlink2
Redirect 301 /mainfolder http://www.test.com/newlink1
```